# $_GET doesn't work when one of the parameters is a URL

Tags: php

$_GET does not work when one of the parameters to the page is a url.

An external page (which I do not have control on) shows an iframe to my page and it passes parameters of which one is:

```
turkSubmitTo=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com
```

When on my page I want to extract other parameters, it gives me NULL for everything, but when I remove the "http" it works. Why is that and what can I do to get the other parameters?

EDIT:
You can try it yourself here:

```
http://www.translate.outofscopes.com/?turkSubmitTo=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com
```

The Array() down there is a print_r of $_GET, you can try to remove the 'http' in the parameter and it will work.
On the localhost it works perfectly.

Comment: Check the requested URL (Either a PHP function or somewhere in $_SERVER) and parse it yourself.

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($_GET);`?

Comment: Could you give me a regex for that?

Comment: This should not be an issue. Can you reproduce this in a minimal example and post it here?

Comment: I don't see any output from `print_r` http://www.translate.outofscopes.com/?turkSubmitTo=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted it after putting there the solution of the answerer. But believe me it returns an Array()

Comment: I'm just taking a stab at this, but I'm guessing that something else is modifying your $_GET array.  I passed your exact url to my script (posted below in my answer) and it showed up in $_GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Something like:

```
$parameters = array();
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $pairs = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  foreach($pairs as $pair) {
    $part = explode('=', $pair);
    $parameters[$part[0]] = urldecode($part[1]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Worked, thanks, I will accept you answer soon it nobody explains to me why my problem occurs. In the mean time, take a +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, pretty easily, but you need to control what's creating the url.  The trick is to urlencode *twice*

```
<?

if ( array_key_exists( 'url', $_GET ) )
{
    echo $_GET['url'] . '<br>';
    echo urldecode( $_GET['url'] ) . '<br>';
}

$url = 'http://example.com/a/index.php?a=123';
$encUrl = urlencode( urlencode( $url ) );

?>
<a href="http://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?url=' . $url; ?>">Not the best</a> - I've seen this fail.
<br>
<a href="http://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?url=' . $encUrl; ?>">Much Better</a>
```